# How to develop apps for Wayland without using a widget toolkit?

Tags: linux, wayland

I would like to know how to develop an application without using widgets toolkits like GTK or QT.  Searching I found that for Xorg it is possible using Xlib.  But how to do this for Wayland?  Is there an Xlib equivalent library for Wayland?  Where should I start my studies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using libwayland-client.
The following are some materials for reference:

https://github.com/emersion/hello-wayland 
https://wayland-book.com/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KbryyNrMYl4